# Android "myLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I found from somewhere on internet, but I get following error on page
**"myLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field"**

Here is my code

```
package com.android.testapp;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);        
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1000);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}

}
```

Get error on last line

```
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

Comment: Do you have any XML file called `myLayout` at your `layout` folder...?

Comment: @gnclmorais no, there is activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you haven no layout file at `layout` folder called `myLayout`... You have to create a valid XML file, with a valid layout in it.

Comment: Ok, what I have to add in that xml file ? I'm new to android and don't know

Comment: If you are that new to Android, you should not start asking questions here, people around here will not like that... Start with the basics, and learn them well: [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).